# Как укоротить программу?

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Подскажите как укоротить программу?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final TextView[] answer = new TextView[6];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView[] question = new TextView[6];
        question[0] = findViewById(R.id.q0);
        question[1] = findViewById(R.id.q1);
        question[2] = findViewById(R.id.q2);
        question[3] = findViewById(R.id.q3);
        question[4] = findViewById(R.id.q4);
        question[5] = findViewById(R.id.q5);

        for (TextView textView : question) {
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        answer[0] = findViewById(R.id.a0);
        answer[1] = findViewById(R.id.a1);
        answer[2] = findViewById(R.id.a2);
        answer[3] = findViewById(R.id.a3);
        answer[4] = findViewById(R.id.a4);
        answer[5] = findViewById(R.id.a5);

        for (TextView textView : answer) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if      (view.getId() == R.id.q0)
            answer[0].setVisibility(answer[0].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.q1)
            answer[1].setVisibility(answer[1].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.q2)
            answer[2].setVisibility(answer[2].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.q3)
            answer[3].setVisibility(answer[3].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.q4)
            answer[4].setVisibility(answer[4].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.q5)
            answer[5].setVisibility(answer[5].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="11" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11111" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22222" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="33"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="33333" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="44" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="44444" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="55" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="55555" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: зачем её укорачивать? Если только отказаться от кучи `View` отказаться, закинуть всё в список, но это только усложнит приложение.

Comment: Вы поставили метку "инспекция-кода". Вы читали её описание? А там написано как правильно оформить вопрос.

Comment: Много есть путей как уменьшить. Используй viewBinding чтоб не писать findViewById, ответы сделай невидимыми в разметке. Ну и список с recyclerView все таки кажется мне лучше - тогда количество вопросов - ответов может быть любым, и костыли в кликЛистнире не понадобятся.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Даже не ожидала такой скорости в ответах)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам не нравятся чередования одинаковых команд для каждой View. Чтобы это исправить, можно заключить их id в массивы:

```
private final Integer[] answersIdArray = new Integer[] {R.id.a0, R.id.a1, R.id.a2, R.id.a3,
    R.id.a4, R.id.a5};
private final Integer[] questionsIdArray = new Integer[] {R.id.q0, R.id.q1, R.id.q2, R.id.q3,
    R.id.q4, R.id.q5};
```

Тогда все действия в onCreate расположатся в одном цикле, а массив questions станет не нужен:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answersIdArray.length; i++) {
    findViewById(questionsIdArray[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
    answer[i] = findViewById(answersIdArray[i]);
    answer[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

В onClick проблема также решается с помощью цикла:

```
if (Arrays.asList(questionsIdArray).contains(view.getId())) {
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsIdArray.length; i++) {
        if (view.getId() == questionsIdArray[i]) {
            answer[i].setVisibility(answer[i].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Это не так удобно и быстро, поэтому, если вам это важно, для onClick я рекомендую использовать Map. Такое решение слегка удлинит код, но увеличит производительность (особенно если количество view будет больше).

```
private final Map<Integer, Integer> questionsIndexMap = createQuestionsIndexMap();

private Map<Integer, Integer> createQuestionsIndexMap() {
    // Ключи - id, значения - индексы.
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsIdArray.length; i++) map.put(questionsIdArray[i], i);
    return map;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (questionsIndexMap.containsKey(view.getId())) {
        View answerView = answer[questionsIndexMap.get(view.getId())];
        answerView.setVisibility(answerView.isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Итоговый код (самый короткий):

```
package com.hfad.foralicemagic;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final TextView[] answer = new TextView[6];
    private final Integer[] answersIdArray = new Integer[] {R.id.a0, R.id.a1, R.id.a2, R.id.a3,
            R.id.a4, R.id.a5};
    private final Integer[] questionsIdArray = new Integer[] {R.id.q0, R.id.q1, R.id.q2, R.id.q3,
            R.id.q4, R.id.q5};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i < answersIdArray.length; i++) {
            findViewById(questionsIdArray[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
            answer[i] = findViewById(answersIdArray[i]);
            answer[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (Arrays.asList(questionsIdArray).contains(view.getId())) {
            for (int i = 0; i < questionsIdArray.length; i++) {
                if (view.getId() == questionsIdArray[i]) {
                    answer[i].setVisibility(answer[i].isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но я согласен с @Михаил, в данном случае лучше всё-таки воспользоваться встроенными инструментами Android.

Comment: Ростислав, спасибо вам огромное! Мне самой еще долго корпеть над этим)))